# Why does XmlReader.IsEmptyElement return different values?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have the next simple xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><work><pageSetup paperSize="9" fitToHeight="0" orientation="landscape"></pageSetup></work>
```

When I run the next code:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inFile))
    while (reader.Read())
        Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, NodeType = {1}, IsEmptyElement ={2}\n", reader.Name, reader.NodeType, reader.IsEmptyElement);
```

The output is:

> Name = xml, NodeType = XmlDeclaration, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> Name = work, NodeType = Element, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> **Name = pageSetup, NodeType = Element, IsEmptyElement =False**
>
> Name = pageSetup, NodeType = EndElement, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> Name = work, NodeType = EndElement, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> ---

As you can see pageSetup's IsEmptyElement=False (I don't know why... see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.isemptyelement.aspx)

But if I foramt the xml (ctrl+alt+shift+b in Notepad++) which becomes with line breaks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<work>
    <pageSetup paperSize="9" fitToHeight="0" orientation="landscape"/>
</work>
```

And run the program, the output is:

> Name = xml, NodeType = XmlDeclaration, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> Name = , NodeType = Whitespace, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> Name = work, NodeType = Element, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> Name = , NodeType = Whitespace, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> **Name = pageSetup, NodeType = Element, IsEmptyElement =True**
>
> Name = , NodeType = Whitespace, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> Name = work,NodeType = EndElement, IsEmptyElement =False
>
> ---

As you can see pageSetup's IsEmptyElement=True

Why is there a different (in pageSetup's IsEmptyElement value) between the two xml files?

Comment: It's not because of the line breaks. It's because in one case it's: `<a></a>` and in the other: `<a/>`.

Comment: maybe the former one contains an empty text node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`MSDN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.isemptyelement(v=vs.110).aspx), `IsEmptyElement` simply reports whether or not the element in the source document had an end element tag.

In the first case, you have have an end element so `IsEmptyElement` returns `false` (although element content is empty), where as in second case you have no end tag which is why you see `IsEmptyElement` set to `true`.